# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, argumentnullexception

here my code is its showing the parameter you have passed is null:-

```
[HttpPost]
public String Indexhome( IEnumerable<Seat>  Seats )
{
     if (Seats.Count(x => x.IsSelected) == 0)
     {
            return "you didnt select any seats";
     }
     else
     {
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           sb.Append("you selected");
           foreach (Seat seat in Seats)
           {
               if (seat.IsSelected)
               {
                   sb.Append(seat.Name + " ,");
               }
            }
           sb.Remove(sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(","), 1);
           return sb.ToString();
     }   
}
```

Comment: first format it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seats will be null if you call the method without matching data / query argument. You need to also check that, like so for instance:

```
[HttpPost]
public String Indexhome( IEnumerable<Seat>  Seats )
{
     if ((Seats == null) || !Seats.Any(s => s.IsSelected))
     {
            return "you didnt select any seats";
     }
     else
     {
           return "you selected " + string.Join(", ", Seats.Where(s => s.IsSelected).Select(s => s.Name));
     }   
}
```

Comment: Yup its shows you didn't select any seats while m selecting seats !!

Comment: @DebashishDwivedi Yes, you need to check the format of the data you're sending, it doesn't match.

Comment: I am selecting seats bt its showing u didnt select any seats

Comment: actually IsSelected is boolean type value

Comment: @DebashishDwivedi Yes I got that... but since you don't show how and what data you send to the controller it's impossible to tell where the problem is on the client side. The data binder doesn't find the "Seats" in the data posted - way before it tries to deserialize. I suggest you open *another question* with the client-side code and show the data sent to the server (you can get this through the developer console network tab).

Comment: okay thanks @lucero

Comment: this my view page

Answer (score 4):

The exception appears because - as Lucero already mentions - `Seats` is `null`. In contrast to a usual method you don´t get a `NullReferenceException` here because `Count` is an extension-method:

```
public static int Count(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
}
```

So as you see the method throws an `ArgumentNullException` instead of a `NullReferenceException` if `source` is `null`.

As an aside don´t use `Count` to check if your collection has items, use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, as it doesn´t enumerate the complete collection and returns when the very first matching the condition was found.

EDIT: If You´d about to use another method which is a normal instance-method you´d get an NRE however:

```
Seats.DoSomething(); // throws NRE when Seats = null
```

So check if the argument is `null` before using it:

```
[HttpPost]
public String Indexhome( IEnumerable<Seat>  Seats )
{
    if (Seats == null || !Seats.Any(x=> x.IsSelected))
        return "you didnt select any seats";
}
```